# Can't switch between fullscreen and windowed mode in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn python creating a small video game using pygame and when I decided to change all my code to OOP everything stop working. I have tried a lot of things, I changed my whole design pattern twice and still not working.

Now I reduced my code to a minimum stage and still can't find where I'm wrong

Can you people help me?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class App(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self._WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
        self._WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480
        self._WINDOW_SIZE = (self._WINDOW_WIDTH, self._WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self._BGIMAGE = pygame.image.load("resources/misrecursos/fondo.jpg")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self._TITLE = "Space Invades"

        self._run = True
        self._fullSC = False
        self._screen = None

    def mainloop(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption(self._TITLE)
        self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self._WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        while self._run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self._run = False
            if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
                self._run = False
            if keys[K_f]:
                self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self._WINDOW_SIZE, pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)

            self._screen.blit(self._BGIMAGE, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mateo. Could you please tell us where you get stuck? I can already tell you that you have an indentation problem in your init function.

Comment: hi, this is the first time I use stack overflow, was a copy paste mistake. Where I am stacked is in the part of switching to Fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh... It's easy.
You should move your line:

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Inside while self._run loop :)

For example:

```
def mainloop(self):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption(self._TITLE)
    self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self._WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)

    while self._run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self._run = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
            self._run = False
        if keys[K_f]:
            self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self._WINDOW_SIZE, pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)

        self._screen.blit(self._BGIMAGE, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're reading the keys only once at the beginning. You need to do it over-and-over inside the main loop. See changes indicated by ALL CAPS comments below:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class App(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self._WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
        self._WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480
        self._WINDOW_SIZE = (self._WINDOW_WIDTH, self._WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self._BGIMAGE = pygame.image.load("resources/misrecursos/fondo.jpg")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self._TITLE = "Space Invades"

        self._run = True
        self._fullSC = False
        self._screen = None

    def mainloop(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption(self._TITLE)
        self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self._WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
####### keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # <---- NOT HERE!

        while self._run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self._run = False
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # <---- DOWN HERE INSIDE GAME LOOP.
            if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
                self._run = False
            if keys[K_f]:
                self._screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
                    self._WINDOW_SIZE,
                    pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)

            self._screen.blit(self._BGIMAGE, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()

        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```